# Styling radio buttons that are not clicked

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a CSS-only way to style those radio buttons of a radio button group that are not clicked after one of them was clicked.

Let's rephrase to clarify. I have a radio button group. Initially, all buttons are in the default state with no button selected. Now I click one radio button so that one now becomes selected. At this point, is there a way to give the other non-selected buttons a different style?

Please note that I don't need help with custom styling radio buttons. I know how to do that. This is specifically about the use case described above.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no attribute that the CSS can be linked to. There is only checked and "not checked". You'll have to do do some JavaScripting to get this done.